# Refactor JavaScript function to TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, refactoring

I just started studying typescript (really just started) and I'm trying to make this function work when running this test:

```
import { convertNumberToEnglishText } from './index';

describe('Number to English converter test suite', () => {
    it('should print zero for 0', () => {
        expect(convertNumberToEnglishText(0)).toBe('zero');
    });

    it('should print zero for 0', () => {
        expect(convertNumberToEnglishText(-0)).toBe('zero');
    });

    it('should print negative one for -1', () => {
        expect(convertNumberToEnglishText(-1)).toBe('negative one');
    });

    it('should print nineteen for 19', () => {
        expect(convertNumberToEnglishText(19)).toBe('nineteen');
    });

    it('should print twenty for 20', () => {
        expect(convertNumberToEnglishText(20)).toBe('twenty');
    });

    it('should print correctly for 41', () => {
        expect(convertNumberToEnglishText(41)).toBe('forty one');
    });

    it('should print correctly for 100', () => {
        expect(convertNumberToEnglishText(100)).toBe('one hundred');
    });

    it('should print correctly for 101', () => {
        expect(convertNumberToEnglishText(101)).toBe('one hundred one');
    });

    it('should print correctly for 739', () => {
        expect(convertNumberToEnglishText(739)).toBe('seven hundred thirty nine');
    });

    it('should print correctly for 1234', () => {
        expect(convertNumberToEnglishText(1234)).toBe('one thousand two hundred thirty four');
    });

    it('should print correctly for 10000', () => {
        expect(convertNumberToEnglishText(10000)).toBe('ten thousand');
    });

    it('should print correctly for 60019', () => {
        expect(convertNumberToEnglishText(60019)).toBe('sixty thousand nineteen');
    });

    it('should print correctly for 67567', () => {
        expect(convertNumberToEnglishText(67567)).toBe('sixty seven thousand five hundred sixty seven');
    });

    it('should print correctly for 99999', () => {
        expect(convertNumberToEnglishText(99999)).toBe('ninety nine thousand nine hundred ninety nine');
    });
});
```

The only error I get in the function is on the first string type declaration in the first line. It says "Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'."

```
export function convertNumberToEnglishText(n: number): string {
    const num = [
        "zero",
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
        "four",
        "five",
        "six",
        "seven",
        "eight",
        "nine",
        "ten",
        "eleven",
        "twelve",
        "thirteen",
        "fourteen",
        "fifteen",
        "sixteen",
        "seventeen",
        "eighteen",
        "nineteen",
    ];
    const tens = [
        "ten",
        "twenty",
        "thirty",
        "forty",
        "fifty",
        "sixty",
        "seventy",
        "eighty",
        "ninety",
    ];
    
        if (n <= 0) return "negative " + convertNumberToEnglishText(-n);
    
        let digit: number = n % 10;
    
        if (n >= 0 && n < 20) return `${num[n]}`;
    
        if (n >= 20 && n < 100) return `${tens[Math.floor(n / 10) - 1]} ${digit != 0 ? num[digit] : ""}`;
    
        if (n >= 100 && n < 1000) {
            return `${num[Math.floor(n / 100)]} hundred ${
                n % 100 == 0 ? "" : convertNumberToEnglishText(n % 100)
            }`;
        }
    
        if (n >= 1000 && n < 10000) {
            return `${num[Math.floor(n / 1000)]} thousand ${
                n % 1000 != 0 ? convertNumberToEnglishText(n % 1000) : ""
            }`;
        }
    
        if (n >= 10000 && n < 20000) {
            return `${num[Math.floor(n / 1000)]} thousand ${
                n % 1000 != 0 ? convertNumberToEnglishText(n % 1000) : ""
            }`;
        }
    
        if (n >= 20000 && n < 100000) {
            return `${tens[Math.floor(n / 10000) - 1]} ${
                num[Math.floor(n / 10000)]
            } thousand ${n % 1000 != 0 ? convertNumberToEnglishText(n % 1000) : ""}`;
        }
}
```

Comment: all of your `return` statements are conditional. You need a `return` statement at the end. A fallback in case the code never hits any of the conditions.

Comment: You said it would return a string, but there are input values for which it doesn't. The compiler is telling you the right thing.

Comment: Thank you guys! It's a lot clearer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every single `return` statement in this function is nested inside a conditional branch. This means that, potentially, that the function could fail all those conditional checks, and no return statement would be executed. This would result in the function returning `undefined` which is the the return value of a function that never explicitly returns a value. This will happen with your function if you pass in a value of more than `100000`, as there is no conditional branch to handle that.

However, the return type of the function is typed as `string`, which means that `undefined` is not an allowed return value. This what the error means.

You need to define what happens when the input is out of the bounds your function handles. There are a lot of ways to do that, depending on what you want to do.

---

You could throw an error as the last line of your function. This would only be hit if all other conditional clauses fail and no return statement is ever executed.

```
throw new Error("Only values below 100,000 are supported")
```

---

You could fallback to just printing the number as digits as the last line:

```
return n.toString()
```

---

Or you could change your return type to `string | undefined` and just add a `return` (with no value) to the end. This tells typescript that the function may return `undefined` and that the caller of this function needs to handle that case.

Comment: Thank you so much! You explained it so well and in such an easy way, thank you again!
Since I'm already here, I'll ask another question if possible... I don't want to return blank spaces sometimes, how can I return nothing instead of using ""?

Comment: To do that, you would use my third possible option in my answer. See https://tsplay.dev/oN9ojW